# If the boundary of a manifold is $C^2$ then the distance to it is also $C^2$ in a neighborhood of the boundary.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

This question comes from the the local property of pseudoconvexity. Pseudoconvexity is is determined by the behaviour of the function of distance to the boundary. In fact it is determined by the differentially geometric property of the boundary in the view of *Levi form*. As in *Demailly's note on complex analytic geometry*, assume the boundary of an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ has $C^2$ boundary. In order to generate Levi form we should make sure $\delta(z) = \mathrm{d}(x, \mathsf{C}\Omega)$ is also $C^2$. But how can I make sure this is actually $C^2$.

One of my thought is using tubular neighbourhood. Locally the map $(x , t) \mapsto x+vt$ where $v$ is the unit normal vector is a diffeomorphism satisfying the nearing point on the boundary to $x+vt$ is $x$. But if the boundary is $C^2$, this map seems to be $C^1$ and so is the inverse $\pi$ of the map. And $\delta(z) = |\pi(z) - z|$ is also $C^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It is proven in Lemma 14.16 in

*Gilbarg, David; Trudinger, Neil S.*, Elliptic partial differential equations of second order. 2nd ed, Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, 224. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. XIII, 513 p. DM 128.00; {$} 47.80 (1983). [ZBL0562.35001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0562.35001).

that if $S$ is a **compact** $C^k$-smooth hypersurface in ${\mathbb R}^N$ ($k\ge 2$) then the distance function to $S$ is $C^k$-smooth in a small neighbourhood of $S$ (away from $S$, of course). Without the compactness assumption, the claim is simply false, an the distance function need not even be differentiable. You should check if  Demailly assumes compactness.

Somehow, the distance function (under proper assumptions)  has higher regularity than one would expect. For instance, the distance function to an **arbitrary** compact subset $S\subset {\mathbb R}^N$ is differentiable in a small neighborhood of $S$ (again, away from $S$).